# How do I delete a row in sql using php?

Tags: php, sql

So, i have been trying really hard to know how to delete a row in sql. I searched a lot on the internet, but i just cant find the answer. I came here to see if anyone can help me.

also, i'm kinda new to this.

```
<?php
$conn = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "a26719", "sde3n13n", "aluno_a26719");

$sql = "SELECT Username, Password, UserID FROM utilizadores";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

echo "<table border='2' style='width:100%'>";
echo "<tr><td> Username </td><td> Password </td><td> User ID </td></tr>";
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) 
{    
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 
{

    echo "<tr><td>" . $row["Username"]. "</td><td>" . $row["Password"]. "</td><td>". $row["UserID"]. "</td></tr>";

}
}

else 
{
    echo "0 results";
}
echo "</table>";


echo "<form action='elimina.php' method='POST'>";
echo "Username: <input type='text' name='username'><br>";
echo "<input type='submit' value='submit'>";
echo "</form>";

$username=$_POST['username'];
$sql="DELETE FROM utilizadores WHERE Username='$username'";




echo "<a href='gestao.php'>Voltar</a>";
?>
```

I know the table works, but the last few lines of deleting don't.

Comment: You build `$sql` but you never actually execute it.

Comment: Your code is also **massively** insecure due to SQL injection. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Comment: You never execute the delete query. You just stick it in a random variable and leave it there. It's not going to jump up and execute itself. Also, your code is vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: `$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);` after the delete. I foresee a completely empty utilizadores table in the near future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
```

The above call is what executes it in the first part of your code. 
You are not executing the DELETE query. You simply define a string and do nothing with it.

Comment: lool, yes that was it. So stupid of me not to see that. Sorry and thanks